# "Not an ARRAY reference" in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl and trying to get used to data structures and references in Perl.

I learned

- `key %hash` returns an array of the keys in `%hash`
- `\{ @array }` returns the reference to the `@array`

So I combined these two and wrote something like this,

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $hash = {
    key1 => 'value1',
    key2 => 'value2'
};

my $keys = \{ keys %$hash }; # Supposed to be an array reference?

print Dumper $keys; # Output 1
print Dumper $keys->[0]; # Output 2
```

which yielded the error `Not an ARRAY reference` at the line of `Output 2`. Also, `Output 1` shows something that looks like a hash reference though it's supposed to be an array reference.

What's wrong with my code?

Similarly, the following code didn't work with the same error.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
my $first_two = \{ @{ $array }[0..1] }; # Isn't it an array ref?
my $first = $first_two->[0];
```

I guess I misunderstand something about array references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you have is this is not correct: `'\{ @array } returns the reference to the @array'` . Instead, the `\` is simply prepended to an existing variable, like this: `\@array`. Braces `{}` are used to create anonymous *hash* references, and brackets `[]` are used to create anonymous *array* references.

In your example, what you want to do is either (1) store the keys as an array and then use `\` to get a reference:

```
my @keys = keys %$hash;
my $keys = \@keys;
```

Or (2) use an anonymous array reference:

```
my $keys = [ keys %$hash ];
```

Here's a good "reference" ;) https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References